# Python:Running multiple session at a time without closing the other sessions

Tags: python, telnet

i need a help for solving this issue, i'm running a python script for checking UDP data transfer between two pcs using IPERF.Problem is, after first telnet and configuration it closes the server session and open the client session which creates an error from iperf server.

```
 def tc01server(ipaddr,login,password):            
        try:
              ss = pexpect.spawn(ipaddr)
              print ss
              ss.expect (":")
              #ss.logfile = open("/tmp/telnetlog", "a") 
              ss.logfile = sys.stdout
              print "connected to telnet"
              print 
        except:
              print "telconnnet connection refused"
              print 
              sys.exit()
        try:
              ss.send(login + "\r")
              ss.expect(":")
              ss.send(password + "\r")
              ss.send("\r\n")

        except:
              print "telconnnet connection refused"
              print 
              sys.exit()     

    def tc01client(ipaddr,login,password):            
        try:
              css = pexpect.spawn(ipaddr)
              print css
              css.expect (":")
              css.logfile = open("/tmp/mynewlog", "w")
              #css.logfile = sys.stdout
              print "connected to telnet"
              print
        except:
              print "telnet connection refused"
              print
              sys.exit()
        try:
              css.send(login + "\r")
              css.expect(":")
              print "connected"
              css.send(password + "\r")
              css.send("\r\n")
        except:
              print "telconnnet connection refused"
              print 
              sys.exit()
```

can anyone please tell me how to run multiple session at a time without closing the other.Thanks in advance.Let me know if not clear.

Comment: Have you tried to use different threads ?

Comment: What is in `ipaddr` ? If it's an ip address, I don't understand the statement `pexpect.spawn(ipaddr)`.

Comment: use `multiprocessing` module and run two processes, one for client and the second one for server; or you could go the easy way and just have two scripts.